# VS Code - Problem with Polish signs in Python's terminal

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get familiar with Python but I'm having some language issue in Terminal tab.

My projects are in folder with a Polish diacritic name in it and when I'm trying to start the programme only thing I can see is red info "Cannot find path ...".

For example, the real path is like **"C:\Users\Łukasz\Projects"** and Python terminal is seeing **"C:\Users\ukasz\Projects"**. **Ł** is missing and it looks like this is the problem...

[image: screenshot of my issue]

Answer (score 0):

This has been [reported](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5736) as a bug upstream.